# How to set a datagridview row cell to dbnull

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbnull

I am trying to set a cell to null using code below but after the code runs the cell is not null and actually = ""

```
isdbnull(cr.Cells(12).Value)
```

returns

```
false
```

using following code

```
DGV_Fields.DataSource = fieldDT
DGV_Fields.AutoGenerateColumns = True
Dim cr As New DataGridViewRow
fieldDT.Columns.Add("Filter", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
fieldDT.Columns("Filter").AllowDBNull = True
DGV_Fields.Columns(12).Width = 59
cr = DGV_Fields.SelectedRows.Item(0)
cr.Cells(12).Value = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Is the grid bound?  If so, what is it bound to?  Generally speaking, using `DBNull` is only appropriate when bound to a `DataTable` or the like.

Comment: yes its bound added code that shows my binding.  The Filter Column is null originally from database, but can also be a non null value.  I need option to set back to null if needed

Comment: Are you sure that that last line actually gets executed?  I'm guessing that the line before it throws an exception because there will be no selected rows immediately after binding.  By the way, there's no point setting `AutoGenerateColumns` after binding.  It is `True` by default so either set it to `False` before binding or don't touch it at all.

Comment: the spacing didn't show, the last 2 line are in a save routine after hitting an apply button in the debugger I stepped through and before executing the last line cr.cells(12).value is still null but after execution it is no longer null, the other columns update properly, there are 15 all together but didn't  think posting it all was wise

Comment: thanks for tip on autogenerate, will remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the last line to

```
cr.Cells(12).Value = nothing
```

now cell is null

Answer (score 0):

This answer refers more to the title (`How to set a datagridview row cell to dbnull`), than to the detailed description.

For my cell only the following worked:

```
Row(0).Cells(0).Value = DBNull.Value
```

Everything else spawned errors or had no effect at all.

The column came from a `Datasource`d one from an SQL query, that had it formatted as `Date NULL`(able)